# Regarding String If Condition

Tags: java, string

I have a lot of static values "ABC" , "DEF" , "FGH" ,"IJK", "JKL" 
I want to have an if condition that checks whether the a String variable exists in this list of static values.  I dont want to have too many or conditions. what is a better way of doing it?

Comment: what have you tried? and state your language next time. from your past records, its Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP you can use the [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) function. Just put all the static values in an array and see if the string is in the array using the function.

If you are using Java then I would recommend checking [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/385467/Java-General/java/Compare-string-String-array) thread out.

Comment: Thanks a lot... The java link that you posted was quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language you're using, but you could put those values into an array, and then do a search on the array to see if the value you're matching exists anywhere in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ArryList as below:

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList.add("ABC");
arrList.add("DEF");
arrList.add("FGH");
arrList.add("IJK");
arrList.add("JKL");
System.out.println(arrList.contains("AAA"))
System.out.println(arrList.contains("FGH"));
```

The example result:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static array of strings. Also [java enum](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is a good idea.